# Does it make sense to cluster asymmetric binary data with Ward's method?

Tags: r, clustering, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean, ward

I'm working with 104x42 data set where all variables are (asymmetric) binary (0-1). I've read that Ward's linkage method doesn't work theoretically properly with binary data beaucause it requests Euclidean distance in a space that i presume should be Euclidean. But I also read that it is possible to [compute Euclidean distance for binary data](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/cmd_proximities_dissim_measure_binary.html#cmd_proximities_dissim_measure_binary). With this distance does it makes sense to cluster with Ward's method? Otherwise, does it make sense with Hamming distance (that is a metric)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume that just as with k-means, the use of Bergman divergences is appropriate. Ward is not going to fail badly if you put other measures in it - it's just *expecting* values from *squared deviations*.

And on *binary* vectors, Euclidean, squared Euclidean, and Hamming will be trivially equivalent.

What matters is the kind of clusters found. K-means and Ward correspond to modeling clusters with *means*, and minimal *squared* deviations from these means. This is fine **if squared deviations from an average make sense for your application**. Which may, or may not, be the case. Most likely, there are other, more appropriate choices.

Comment: Thank you very much. About what you said about mean, I suppose I can define its notion and derivates for binary data after I put them in a metric space with PCA/MCA/(N)MDS and so i could cluster new points with k-means or ward's method or other methods by using Euclidean distance. Am i right?

Comment: It's not so much the *notion* (that cannot change, out it isn't the euclidean mean) but rather he *semantic* of the mean *and* least-squares optimization must be meaningful for your application. IMHO they make most sense on *continuous* variables of the exact same scale (e.g., position variables).

Comment: So you should show that the *optimization* problem relates to the problem that you are trying to solve.